# Vanishing of higher homotopy groups of finite complexes

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

Throughout, let $X$ be a *connected finite* CW-complex. If the universal covering of $X$ is contractible, then $\pi_n(X)=0$ for all $n \geq 2$. In this case $X$ is a model for $B\pi_1(X)$.

I am wondering whether this is the only reason why higher homotopy groups vanish above a certain degree. More precisely:

> **Question:** Let $k \geq 3$ be an integer. Can it happen that $\pi_n(X) = 0$ for all $n \geq k$ and $\pi_{k-1}(X)\neq 0$?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No, it cannot happen. In [a paper by McGibbon and Neisendorfer](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02566349), it is proven that if *X* is a 1-connected space and its mod-p-homology is non-zero in some degree, but zero in all higher degrees, then the $\pi_n X$ contain a subgroup of order p for infinitely many *n*. This can be applied to the universal cover of your *X*.

Comment: This shows that for a finite dimensional simply connected space with finitely many homotopy groups, those groups are vector spaces over $\mathbb Q$. Since there are finitely presented groups containing $\mathbb Q$, my guess is that this can actually happen.

Comment: @BenWieland If $X$ is simply-connected and all its homotopy groups are $\mathbb{Q}$-vector spaces, then also all of its reduced homology groups are $\mathbb{Q}$-vector spaces (see e.g. Theorem 9.3 in *Rational Homotopy Theory* by Felix, Halperin and Thomas). For a finite complex this cannot happen. If you only require finite-dimensional, I don't know, however.